# How to Hide Table in MVC View when there is No Data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am populating my datatable using Linq.

I have hard-coded headers. And populating body columns with Linq. Following is my code.

```
<table id="tableID">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th style="width:2%;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                     @if(Model.Values !=null)
                {
                    foreach(var value in Model.Values)
                    {   
                        <tr>
                            <td>@value.Name</td>
                            <td>@value.ID</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }


                </tbody>
            </table>
```

What I am thinking to do here, if there is no data table should not be visible.I thought of moving my conditional check if model is returning null prior to table creation but it will throw exception. I am fairly new to MVC. Any suggestion is appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put one `if` around table as well to check if property is not null and count of that list is greater than 0 then table should be rendered.

```
 @if(Model  != null)
    {
    if(Model.Values != null && Model.Values.Count != 0)
    {
    <table id="tableID">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th style="width:2%;"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @foreach(var value in Model.Values)
                        {   
                            <tr>
                                <td>@value.Name</td>
                                <td>@value.ID</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    }
}
```

Comment: I initially thought about it but was getting compilation error. But this is the solution. Just have to edit a little to mark it as answer.

Comment: Had to add @ against foreach to prevent compilation error. After having markups like <table> etc. you need to add @ symbol again for code lookup.

Comment: add @ sign before foreach

Comment: You need to add it. In order to prevent compilation error. check my comment above. Once you have razor markup added after @symbol, it looses the reference within code block. You need to add @ again for code look-up reference.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Works like charm now.